# Java 7 code using multiple if and for block refactoring into java 8

Tags: foreach, java-8, stream

Can any one please convert below snippet into java 8 using stream:

```
private String findEmp(String nameOrIdToCompare){
           for (Employee emp: empArray){
            if(emp.getAge() > 60){
                //some code
            }
            if (nameOrIdToCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(emp.getID())){
                              //some code
                return titleOrIdToCompare;
            }
            else if(emp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOrIdToCompare)){
                                //some code
                return titleOrIdToCompare;
            }
        }
           return null;
     }
```

I was trying to convert above code using java 8 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Logic can be updated as required inside map()

```
 public String findEmp(String name, Employee[] empArray) {
return Arrays.stream(empArray)
        .peek(emp -> {
            if (emp.getAge() > 60) {
                System.out.println(emp.getAge());
            }
        })
        .filter(emp -> emp.getName().equals(name) || emp.getId() == name)
        .map(Employee::getName).findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

}